# how to know if an activity has started already

Tags: android

I'm working in a app ,where I filter if screen is on or off and launch an activity when the screen is on, but sometime it launch the activity but the activity was started already , i would like to ask you if it was any way to know inside  my app if an activity is already launched.

When i start the activity i added this code

```
intent11.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: Take a look at [onNewIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)), it maybe suits your purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you can set variable with activity life cycle

```
class IAMActivity extends Activity {
    static boolean isStart = false;

  public void onStart() {
     super.onStart();
     isStart = true;
  } 
  public void onStop() {
     super.onStop();
     isStart = false;
   }
 }
```

Comment: ok i will try, but just one more question , in my activity when screen goes off my activity goes to onResumen()?? and them when screen goes on goes to onStart() ??? is this lifecylce correct? thanks.

Comment: I think when screen off activity goes to onPause() state and when screen on activity goes to onResume() state.


http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html

Sorry for edit.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you are looking for:

```
 class MyActivity extends Activity {
 static boolean alreadyLaunched = false;

  @Override
  public void onStart() {
     super.onStart();
     alreadyLaunched = true;
  } 

  @Override
  public void onStop() {
     super.onStop();
     alreadyLaunched = false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restrict your activity to one instance, you can set the `launchMode` in the manifest file to either `singleTask` or `singleInstance`, depending on your requirements.

```
<activity
     android:launchMode="singleTask"
     ...>
...
</activity>
```

With `singleTask` a new intent is delivered via `onNewIntent()` instead of `onCreate()`.

See [<activity>](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) for more details.